# Retrieve Google Sheets column by header name

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to retrieve a column dynamically by it's column name (header)?

Instead of:

```
var values = sheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();
```

Something like: (Just for simplicity)

```
var values = sheet.getRange(sheet.column.getHeader("name").getValues();
```

Please keep in mind that Google Apps Script is roughly ES3.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simple one-line function you can copy. It returns the column number (A = 1, B = 2, etc.) for use in `getRange`, for example.

```
function getColByHeader(name) {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('1:1').getValues()[0].indexOf(name) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write one ;)

```
function getColValuesByName(sheet, name) {
  var index = sheet.getRange(1,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].indexOf(name);
  index++;
  return sheet.getRange(1,index,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
}
```

Comment: It should be `sheet.getLastRow() - 1`

Answer (score 1):

Although there is no direct way, there are plenty of ways to get what you want with a little set up:

- Get all data and filter it(no set up):

```
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var headers = values.splice(0,1);
headerIdx = headers[0].indexOf("name");
values = values.map(function(row){return [row[headerIdx]];})
```

- Named ranges set up:

If you have named ranges associated with that column,

```
spreadsheet.getRangeByName('Sheet Name!name').getValues();//where 'name' is a named range
```

- Developer metadata set up:

If you have developer metadata associated with that column,

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .createDeveloperMetadataFinder()
    .withKey(/*METADATA_KEY_ASSOCIATED_WITH_COLUMN*/)
    .find()[0]
    .getLocation()
    .getColumn()
    .getValues();
```